# specify keyPath with multiple tables in indexedDb

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

in my project I'm using indexedDb through the wrapper [Dexie.js](http://dexie.org/). The goal is to fetch the data directly from the indexedDb instead of calling api all the time.

Since I might change/delete some data, from time to time, I use a version number to keep track of what is present in the user cache. So when the application starts I receive the version of the db, if that matches the version in the cache I fetch the indexedDb, otherwise I will delete the indexedDb and fetch from the server the new data.

The problem is that I can't find a way to update the version value without adding another entry. Right now this is what I'm doing:

```
       db.version(1).stores({
              buildings: "id, name, address, lat, long, purchased, [lat+long]",
              versions: "id, version",
          });

          db.open().then((el) => {
              console.log(el);
              this.eventBus.$on("refresh-map", () => {
                  this.fetchHexagons();
              });
          }).catch(Dexie.MissingAPIError, (e) => {
              console.log("Couldn't find indexedDB API");
              console.log(e);
              rollback = true;
          }).catch((error) => {
              console.log(`error: ${error}`);
          });

          db.versions.toArray((res) => {
              if (res.length > 0 && res[0].version != version.body.model_version) {
                  db.buildings.clear().then(() => {
                      console.log("clearing buildings");
                  });
              }

              db.versions.update(1, { version: "2"}).then((update) => {
                  if (!update) {
                      db.versions.put({ version: version.body.model_version });
                  }
              });
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
dexie.es.js?f8d5:1384 Unhandled rejection: Error: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value.
```

I just want to make sure that whenever I add/put the version field I only substitute that value without adding anything else: that way the db in the "versions" table will always have one element.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
db.versions.put({ version: version.body.model_version });
```

...needs to provide an id:

```
db.versions.put({ id: someUniqueId, version: version.body.model_version });
```

Another option is to use an auto-incremented primary key. If so, you would need to recreate the DB (primary keys may not be changed on existing db):

```
db.version(1).stores({
    buildings: "id, name, address, lat, long, purchased, [lat+long]",
    versions: "++id, version",
});
```

To recreate the db:

```
db.delete().then(()=>db.open())
```